# I can't find Change Source Control in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2012

It should be under File -> Source control. I want to move a project from one tfs to another, by disconnecting the project, login as another user and upload.

But I cant find where to log out :-/

Comment: Is the current project under source control?

Comment: Are your Scource-Control Settings Ok? Tools -> Options -> Scource Control

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the solution Checked-out. Once, the solution is checked-out, go to File->Source Control again